# linux serial: reading parity bit for 9bit communication

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart, parity

I need to read the 9th bit off the UART port that send 9bit data communication.

Currently I have enabled parity but disable the checking so that I can properly read the data off the uart port. But I need to actually know what the 9th bit is on the serial port can someone help me please.

I there anyway to pass the 9th bit up through the hardware.

Comment: The parity bit is not readable in the received data register.  You can only infer its value by knowing the parity configuration and whether a parity error was detected. *"I there anyway to pass the 9th bit up through the hardware."* -- Yes, with a UART (e.g. 16950) that supports a 9-bit frame.  See http://superuser.com/questions/411386/seeking-9-bit-serial-port-card-for-windows-pc/411438#411438

Comment: Solved. I built a different parser to be more robust.

Comment: Its nice you solved your problem, but for those of us having the same issue, it would have been good to post HOW you solved it.

Comment: For a Linux C program that can detect when 9th bit (8+parity) is mark (or 1), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193363/stty-serial-port-settings-for-parity-not-persistent/57318783#57318783